# Edit Interactions-Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a filter for different customer categories- Platinum, Gold, Silver, Iron 
& two bar graphs for customers and products.
I want that when I select a category from the filter, the graphs should show only those customers and products with the help of edit options.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If your filter columns are in any way linked to the chart (same table, relationship between two different tables is active) this should work automatically.

However it could be that someone tunred the interaction off. To see the interaction icons click on your filter visual and go to `Format > Edit Interactions`. Now you will see on all the other charts/filter this two symbols:

[image]

If the left diagram icon is grey: This means your selected visual will interact with this visual.

If the right circle icon is grey: This means your selected visual will not interact with this visual.